# How to develop libvirt C++ apps in Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, libvirt

I want to develop c++ apps that use libvirt api (libvirt/libvirt.h) in Mac OS. In Ubuntu once I installed libvirt-dev, it was compiling fine. but in mac I cannot find a way to install libvirt-dev. Can someone point me to the correct path. Thanks :D

Comment: With **homebrew** http://brew.sh The command would be `brew install libvirt`

Comment: yup that installed correctly, but when compiling with GCC it cannot find the libvirt.h , that issue was fixed by installing libvirt-dev in Ubuntu, bt homebrew does not have a libvirt-dev formula. :(

Comment: Install `pkgconfig` with **homebrew** too using `brew install pkgconfig`. Then you can use `pkgconfig` to get the switches for the compiler... `gcc program.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libvirt) -o program`

Comment: You can try just getting the flags and switches just on its own with `pkg-config --cflags --libs libvirt`. You can also use those flags and switches with the Apple-supplied `clang/clang++` compiler instead of with the GNU compiler I suggested above.

Comment: Thank you so much , I can now understand. That worked well :D

Comment: You are welcome - good luck with your project. I may write it up as an answer later for other folks to see.

Comment: Thanks, yes please do :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install **homebrew** first, from [the Homebrew website](http://brew.sh), then you will be able to simply install `libvirt` with:

```
brew install libvirt
```

If you want to compile against `libvirt`, I would further suggest you install `pkgconfig` with:

```
brew install pkgconfig
```

After that you can use `pkgconfig` to find the switches and flags you need for `libvirt` like this:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libvirt
```

which will give you something like:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libvirt/3.4.0/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/libvirt/3.4.0/lib -lvirt
```

So, in conclusion, you will then be able to compile `C` code with:

```
gcc program.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libvirt) -o program
```

or

```
clang program.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libvirt) -o program
```

or C++ code with:

```
clang++ program.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libvirt) -o program
```